# maven shade plugin custom transformer

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

Given [maven shade plugin resource transformers](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html), how can we create custom ones?

I've tried adding the shade plugin to my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And creating a class that implements ResourceTransformer. But when I run it, I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (default) on
>   project foo: Unable to parse configuration of mojo
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade for parameter
>   transformers: Cannot load implementation hint
>   'test.transformer.TestTransformer' -> [Help 1]

The transformer is on the same classpath as the project I'm running the build on, which, I'm guessing is the problem. Is there a way to add in an extension that brings in other transformers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See in the [next section of the instructions](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/use-shader-other-impl.html):

- create a maven project that contains `test.transformer.TestTransformer` with the appropriate dependencies in its `pom.xml`.
- in the original project project's `pom.xml` in `project.build.plugins.plugin[.id='maven-shade-plugin']` add the above maven project as a dependency.

Comment: I knew I missed something simple. Thanks for finding it!